# Pen tool in Flex/Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Is there any way drawing lines/curves in flex/fb4 -like pen tool?
Because it is not a practical method drawing with only `<s:Line/>`'s. Maybe an external tool which lets you draw and get the code for flex/fb4?

I want to draw something in IDE as a part of my application, my application is not going to be a drawing application.

Comment: Do you want to create an app with drawing features?  Or do you want to draw something in your IDE and use it as part of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw your interface in Illustrator. Run it through catalyst, and make a custom component. Or you can export flash components( swf's so no code ) from Illustrator directly IIRC.